# Kapt not generating classes in Instant app feature module

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-instant-apps, kapt

I am using dagger2 in my android application. It is not generating dagger component classes even though there is no errors.

I have enabled the annotation processors in the setttings and restart my android studio but that didn't work for me. I read this thread too [Dagger2 not generating Daggercomponent classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855361/dagger2-not-generating-daggercomponent-classes) and read on one thread that `apt` is deprecated so I am using `annotationProcessor`

Base Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    application project(':app')
    feature project(":main")
    feature project(":tv")  

    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'

    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    api "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

    api "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9"
    api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9"

    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.0.0"

    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'

    // new version 1.5.2 has some multi dex issue
    debugApi 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseApi 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

tv feature build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':base')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}
```

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

NetComponent.kt

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, NetModule::class))
interface NetComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

`apt` generates dagger classes inside apt directory but there is no such dagger generated classes now even though I searched in entire project directory.

[image]

I see that its not generating `DaggerNetComponent` class, as there is no errors too on compilation. Does anyone know what could be the issue ?

Comment: Is this module an instant app module? Post the whole build.gradle, please.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Please see. I have added it

Comment: I've created a bug report here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20244 Let's see what happens.

Comment: Ok, there's been progress. Turns out after you apply my Original answer the classes are generated, but they don't show in the Project window. After you right-click and select Synchronize, they should appear (after you build the project). Can you confirm this?

Comment: I Synchronized it but no luck

Comment: Have you tried with Kotlin 1.1.4-3? I just noticed in your question you have an older version.

Comment: I am using `ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'`, I updated after posting this question

Comment: Ok, go through the project referenced in the Kotlin issue and look for anything different/suspicious. For example in your dependencies you have `application project(...)` and `feature project(...)`. Base feature does NOT depend on any other features and certainly not application modules, that's the point of a base module. Dependencies are specified using `implementation` or `api` configuration. `application` and `feature` have no meaning here as far as I know. Visit this walkthrough https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0, then get back to your app.

Comment: Where is your NetComponent in your project? Inside base module or inside tv module?

Comment: @EugenPechanec I think I found something :) wait lemme try

Comment: @EugenPechanec I have to add this `api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'` in each feature module where I am using dagger2 even though I have same in base module, basically there should not be need to do but anyways thank you so much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>Your module is an instant app feature module. And it looks like kapt doesn't support those yet.</s>

I cannot back this with a source but this should work:

- feature module

  - library module + dagger + kapt

Move everything from your feature module to a library module. Then make the feature module depend on the library module.

Library modules do support kapt.

[This sample project](https://github.com/mustafaberkaymutlu/UV-Index) uses Dagger and Kapt in Instant App Feature modules and it works out-of-the-box. There must be some other issue with your project setup, which is not related to Dagger or annotation processing.

Go through the [Instant App Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0) and make sure you didn't misunderstand anything.

The original answer should then work.

#### Original answer

Use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` configuration. As in:

```
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9"
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
```

If you're using databinding add this as well:

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-beta4"
```

Don't forget to update the version when you use different build plugin version.

Kotlin plugin doesn't pick up `annotationProcessor` dependencies, we have to use `kapt` dependencies instead.

Finally, to use latest version of Kotlin annotation processor put this at the top of your module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Kotlin support for `com.android.feature` modules was [added in Kotlin 1.1.4](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/f053d79994cf8af9d80b90956ec95063767f1b58), make sure you use at least that.

Comment: Ah ok. Where it generates classes ? any path ?

Comment: Output of an annotation processor is responsibility of that annotation processor. Root for kapt output is `/build/generated/source/kapt/`. So for Dagger it's `/build/generated/source/kapt/<flavor>/<whatever-package-your-original-class-was-in>`.

Comment: Nope. It is not gerating kapt folder

Comment: Hey @EugenPechanec, do we still need "generateStubs"?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Good point, as long as you `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` you don't need `kapt.generateStubs = true`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec It is still not generating. I did clean and build project multiple times :/

Comment: @Williams: Perhaps you could update the listing for your gradle dependencies clause?  That is where the problem is, most likely (presuming you are applying the "kotlin-kapt" plugin)

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike It's my updated build.gradle https://pastebin.com/ANyjE72j all are updated

Comment: @Williams Please read the updated answer. It's a workaround but it's the best that's available now.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I am working on instant app so I need feature module. That's why I can't make it library module

Comment: I added `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in feature module too, that created kapt directory in `generated/source` but it is empty directory :/. I did clean and build

Comment: @Williams Feature modules can depend on library modules and library modules support kotlin annotation processor. I don't see a problem.

Comment: what do you mean by library module here ? Is it base module ?

Comment: What I have add in library ? dagger components and module ? Is feature module activity is accessible inside library module ?

Comment: For simplicity move all code from feature to library (code, XML, manifest). Then make the feature module dependent on library and expose the code to its own consumers 'api project(":library-module-name")'. Now any module depending on the feature module can see the code in the library module.

Comment: My base build.gradle is correct, github example says same to do `feature project(':query')
    application project(':app')`.

Comment: I have to add this api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11' kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11' in each feature module where I am using dagger2 even though I have same in base module, basically there should not be need to do. Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're right! I completely missed that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If you see my base build.gradle I have `application project(':app')
    feature project(":main")
    feature project(":tv")` which is correct

Comment: Thank you so much +1 I will award bounty to your answer

Comment: @Nancy It should work if you have Dagger API only in the base project, it will be transitive. But the compiler apparently needs to be in every module. It's OK if you post this finding as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

In your **base** module `build.gradle` you have

```
dependencies {
    // some other stuff        

    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

While `com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11` is transitively available to your **feature** module due to `api` keyword, `kapt` does **not** make `com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11` transitively available to your **feature** module.

Therefore you need to add `com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11` to all your **feature** module for dagger to generate classes

In **feature** module `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    // some other stuff        

    // add kapt 
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: @KenZira do you want to provide some additional information?

Answer (score 1):

I literally just had this issue.

Try removing 'jre7' from the Kotlin stdlib dependency.

Comment: Nope. I re-build my project and debug/debugFeature is empty inside kapt