# android studio databinding error Unresolved reference: databinding

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, android-studio-3.0

I am getting this error when trying to bind .xml layout into .kt files.
This is my attempt on creating an app with Instant App support feature

```
Error:10:35:11.151 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] e: ./../feature/src/main/java/my/${projectname}/${projectname}/feature/view/splash/fragment/LandingFragment.kt: (14, 37): Unresolved reference: databinding
10:35:11.154 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] e: ./../feature/src/main/java/my/${projectname}/${projectname}/feature/view/splash/fragment/LandingFragment.kt: (22, 42): Unresolved reference: FragmentLandingBinding
10:35:11.379 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':feature:compileDebugKotlin'.
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation error. See log for more details
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
10:35:11.380 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
10:35:11.381 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:35:11.381 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
10:35:11.381 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':feature:compileDebugKotlin'.
10:35:11.381 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
10:35:11.382 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
10:35:11.382 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
10:35:11.382 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
10:35:11.383 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
10:35:11.383 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
10:35:11.383 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
10:35:11.383 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
10:35:11.383 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
10:35:11.383 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
10:35:11.383 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
10:35:11.384 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
10:35:11.385 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:415)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:389)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:251)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:215)
10:35:11.386 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
10:35:11.387 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
10:35:11.387 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
10:35:11.387 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
10:35:11.387 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
10:35:11.387 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
10:35:11.387 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
10:35:11.387 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 29 more
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
10:35:11.388 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
10:35:11.389 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 13s
```

This is my build.gradle(Project: projectname)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.versions = [
            'kotlin_version' : '1.2.21',
            'anko_version' : '0.10.4',
            'glide_version' : '4.5.0',
            'android_plugin_version' : '3.1.0-alpha06'

    ]
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$versions.android_plugin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application_id"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true

    }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
}
```

my build.gradle(Module:Base)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    application project(':app')
    feature project(':feature')
}
```

Build.gradle(Module: feature)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$versions.kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$versions.anko_version"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$versions.glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$versions.glide_version"
    implementation project(':base')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$versions.android_plugin_version"
}
```

and Build.Gradle(module:Instant app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

Seems like the problem is because on databinding auto bind layout.

I refered to [Android Databinding : package does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934249/android-databinding-package-does-not-exist)

and [Kapt not generating classes in Instant app feature module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080018/kapt-not-generating-classes-in-instant-app-feature-module?rq=1)

Did I missed something on my build.gradles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found workaround for this...
from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63814741

adding

```
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding = true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

in `gradle.properties` files kinda solve the issue... but I doubt that this is a solution... but for now... this is how the problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue recently. Adding kapt plugin to app level build.gradle file solved my issue. The problem is that you already have that plugin in your gradle file. Maybe issue is resolved after some time but I want to leave this answer because this question comes up first in Google search.

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`